# Normal Map Baking Artifacts

Tags: normals, texture-baking, baking, normal-map, artifacts

I have this model, which when baking the normal map always has artifacts in the same place - on the upper ring, into which many "beams/pipes" are inserted. The mesh consists of several objects joined into one, so the geometry of the "beams" was not directly connected to the ring in any way. Also Bevel modifier was applied on the model with "Harden Normals" enabled. What can cause this problem and is there any way to get rid of these artifacts when baking directly in blender? I've attached some images for clarity [image][image]

[image][image]

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I wouldn't like to share my file, it's a game model which will be for sale and I don't want anyone to steal it. Do you have any recommendation on what can I try to solve this?

Comment: if this is just about the torus, just share the torus? (high-poly and low-poly)

Comment: I'm not baking from a multires model, I'm baking a  texture from a bump node

Comment: Any help without a file is going to be a guessing game-- I'd say that if you run into problems, you say, okay, I guess I'm not ready to be selling stuff until I understand how this stuff works better, and write it off.  I don't see anything weird in your final image, which is presumably the normal map in use.  Wouldn't recommend combining custom normals (incl. sharp edges) and a normal map: instead, use an object space normal map on a smooth, default normal copy (can bake from that to tangent if desired.)  Bump->normal depends on the bump, so shader nodes are a minimum to tackle the problem.

Comment: Ok, I've tried so much stuff and nothing works, how do I share a file? I'm new to this platform

Comment: Recommended, use https://blend-exchange.com/ and put their code in your question.  Ideally here, we want the file ready to hit "bake", with any textures used for the bump packed into the file.